# Change value when is uploaded reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fetch

So I'm making a code that receive value from python scripts, it works, If you console it you can the the value.

```
    fetch('/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data

    }).then(response => response.json()
    ).then(json => {
        setData(json)
        console.log(json)
    });
```

And I have this too

```
        <textarea id="text">
            {data}
        </textarea>
```

The problem is that when the code works and console the value, nothing appears in the textarea, how can I refresh the text area when the fetch happen.

Comment: Please share the output of `console.log(json)`

Comment: You need to use `value={data}` and also stick to either controlled or uncontrolled behaviour https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag

Comment: @vishwasmeshram the output is normal text

Comment: @YuryTarabanko IT WORKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const [data, setData] = useState("")`

`<textarea value={data}/>`